# What am I doing wrong with the Drupal 7 Exif module?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, exif

I am trying to get a gallery set up that will display EXIF and other metadata from images that are uploaded. To do this I am using Drupal 7's `exif` module, which is supposed to draw the data into fields automatically.

I set up a content type, `exif_image`. I added an image field, and a field named `field_exif_resolutionunit` to the type. I then uploaded an image of that content type. The image does have a resolution unit exif field, but it doesn't show up in the node for the uploaded image.

I did this all on a fresh install of Drupal 7. What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Make sure the widget type is set to `metadata from image` for the field `field_exif_resolutionunit` that you created.

In the field properties, make sure the `exif field data` is set to `name of the field is the exif field name`.  If this doesn't work, try changing this to the exif data property that you want and see if that makes a difference.

In your exif module settings at `admin/config/media/exif/settings`, make sure you have the Nodetype set for the content type you created.  And make sure the `Refresh on node update` is checked off.

Comment: That's an awful lot of questions for an answer ;)

Comment: Hah! Thanks, Clive.  Rephrased my answer.